# Capturing parameters sed

Tags: sed, find

I am trying to replace occurences in bunch of html files. I want to update the files with the new subdomain name.

old urls look like this :

**https://123.olddomain.com/wp-content/**

New ones should look like that :

**https://newdomain.com/static/123.newdomain.com/wp-content/**

I have tried in the folowing expression to update all subdomains html files at once

```
sudo find . -type f -exec sed -i 's+https:\/\/\([0-9]\).olddomain.com\/wp-content\/+https:\/\/newdomain.com\/static\/$1.newdomain.com\/wp-content\/+g' {} +
```

$1 does not seem to capture my rexpression [0-9]

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Should it be `\1` instead of `$1` ?  And maybe the `\([0-9]\)` should read `\([0-9]*\)` ?

Comment: What @steve said, and you seem to be escaping the `/` characters even though you're using an alternate command delimiter (`+`).  Also, your expression doesn't allow for more than a single digit at the start of the old domain name, and the dots should be escaped. There are, simply speaking, a bunch of typos in the expression that you ought to have fixed before trying to run it with `sudo` and `find`.

Comment: You can experiment with your sed command by doing `echo 'https://123.olddomain.com/wp-content/' | sed 's+http.... '` and seeing how it behaves before trying to run it with sudo and find

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to handle such problems is via the use of shell variables and proper quoting on whether the variable appears on the left hand side of a sed substitution or the right.

```
## make the old var pluggable in the lhs
old='https://123.olddomain.com/wp-content/'
old_lhs=$old
for c in \\ \[ \^ \$ . \* / ;do
old_lhs=${old_lhs//"$c"/\\"$c"}
done

### make the new var pluggable on rhs
new='https://newdomain.com/static/123.newdomain.com/wp-content/'
new_rhs=$new
for c in \\ \& $'\n' /;do
  new_rhs=${new_rhs//"$c"/\\"$c"}
done

## now traverse the tree and detect files
## that have the old domain string in it
# then pass them in multiple chunks to sed
find . -type f \
  -exec grep -qFe "$old" {} \; \
  -exec sed -i -e "s/$old_lhs/$new_rhs/g" {} + \
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all suggestions, very helpful
I ended up making it work with that :

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's+\([0-9]*\).olddomain.com/wp-content/+\1.newdomain.com/wp-content/+g' {} +
```

`\1` is capturing all digit contained in subdomains and identified by `\([0-9]*\)`.

Comment: But your output does not match the expected output. Where is the static component?